# Alterar o título da Actionbar em versões antigas

Tags: java, android

Olá tenho quatro telas no meu aplicativo android e quero que em cada tela a action bar tenha um nome diferente. Tentei trocar o título usando `getActionBar().setTile()`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só que como tenho a API 9 como versão mínima e não consigo usar. Há alguma outra opção que funcione a partir da API 9?

Comment: Denis, para facilitar a vida de quem está respondendo, e a indexação / busca por respostas, evite colar *print screens* de código. É sempre melhor colar o código em si no corpo da pergunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para versões mais antigas você vai precisar usar o método [`getSupportActionBar()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html#getSupportActionBar()).

Veja que para isso sua classe terá que herdar de [`ActionBarActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html) ou [`AppCompatActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) ou invés de `Activity`:

```
public class MinhaAtividade extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Meu titulo");            
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_minha_tela);
    }

    // ... demais métodos
}
```